# On the origin of the concept of aliasing & the Discrete Fourier Transform frequency axis

Tags: mathematics, harmonic-analysis

The development of the fast Fourier transform (FFT) is attributed to Cooley & Tukey, both of whom have written a lot about its historical development. However, I am searching for early publications that showed how people made the discrete frequency axis after FFT.

For example, if we have $N$ data points (where $N$ is an even or odd number), the FFT output also consists of $N$ data points. The specific question is:

1. Who came up with the equation or the proof that the frequency spacing in discrete Fourier transform is $\frac k L$, where $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots, N-1$ and $L$ is the total duration of time for which the signal was acquired.
2. I am sure the concept of folding or aliasing must be in the same work.

Here is one earlier example by Tukey himself from 1950s: [The measurement of power spectra](https://archive.org/details/TheMeasurementOfPowerSpectra/page/n24).

Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean what is variously called the sampling theorem, Kotelnikov theorem or Shannon-Nyquist theorem (erroneously), see Bissell's remarks to his [translation of Kotelnikov's 1933 paper](http://ict.open.ac.uk/classics/1.pdf). The term ["aliasing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Historical_usage) was borrowed from radio engineering, and predates even Nyquist's 1928 paper.

Comment: It is interesting, I was reading Hamming's Numerical Methods and he attributed aliasing to Tukey (the Cooley Tukey pair). Most likely aliasing is older as you said. I got more details here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335829/origin-of-the-theorem-related-to-the-integral-transform-pair